# Задача "Полиглоты" (Python) - оптимизация кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Каждый из N школьников некоторой школы знает Mᵢ языков. Определите, какие языки знают все школьники и языки, которые знаетхотя бы один из школьников.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> Первая строка входных данных содержит количество школьников N. Далее идет N чисел Mᵢ, после каждого из чисел идет Mᵢ строк, содержащих названия языков, которыезнает i-й школьник. Длина названий языков не превышает 1000 символов, количестворазличных языков не более 1000. 1≤N≤1000, 1≤Mᵢ≤500.
>
> Формат вывода
>
> В первой строке выведите количество языков, которые знают все школьники. Начиная со второй строки - список таких языков. Затем - количество языков, которые знает хотя бы один школьник, на следующих строках - список таких языков.

Моя реализация:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
b = 0
c = 0
d = []
# ввод исходных данных
for i in range(n):
    b = int(input())
    for j in range(b):
        c = str(input())
        d.append(c)
    a.append([b, d])
    d = []
# 　создание полного списка языков
for i in range(n):
    d.append(a[i][1])
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a += set(d[i])
a = set(a)
# получение списка общих языков
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    a = list(a)
    c.append(a[i])
c = set(c)
for i in range(len(d)):
    c &= set(d[i])
print(len(c))
print(*c, sep="\n")
print(len(a))
print(*a, sep="\n")
```

Проверяющая система код приняла, однако, меня терзают смутные сомнения:

1) как-то очень уж накручено получилось - можно ли как-то оптимизировать?

2) много переменных - нехорошо?

3) одни и те же переменные периодически обнуляю и использую для разных целей - нехорошо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы работал с множествами:

исходный список языков:

```
In [65]: stud_langs = [['english', 'russian'], ['english', 'ukrainian', 'russian'], ['english', 'german', 'ukrainian', 'russian']]
```

преобразуем к списку множеств:

```
In [66]: stud_langs = [set(x) for x in stud_langs]

In [67]: stud_langs
Out[67]:
[{'english', 'russian'},
 {'english', 'russian', 'ukrainian'},
 {'english', 'german', 'russian', 'ukrainian'}]
```

пересечение всех множеств - языки, которыми владеют все школьники:

```
In [68]: set.intersection(*stud_langs)
Out[68]: {'english', 'russian'}
```

объединение всех множеств - языки, которыми владеет хотя бы один из школьников:

```
In [69]: set.union(*stud_langs)
Out[69]: {'english', 'german', 'russian', 'ukrainian'}
```